# Web API - Default Routing for web URL

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a net web API set up. The URL I want to route to is https://localhost:44378, but Web API forces me to use https://localhost:44378/api/status.

How do I set up a default so if any traffic comes in at https://localhost:44378? redirects to the same code as https://localhost:44378/api/status?

I have tried to use * as the routing default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a WebApiConfig.cs in the App_Start folder of your application.

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            .......

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Try removing "api" from the routeTemplate.

For .net core web api, the default is a Route attribute in the controller.

If I use the template to create a Web Api in .Core it gives me a ValuesController.

```
namespace CoreApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
```

Just change the route attribute and remove api

```
        [Route("[controller]")]
```

Comment: Hi by default web api .net core has     `code app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
                //defaults: new { controller = "TravelPortSync", action = "FullSync" }
                );
            }); `

Comment: @vaughn,  I've edited my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: hi that worked if my url is https://localhost:44378/api is there a way to make it work for https://localhost:44378

Comment: Yes. You just remove the api from the Route as shown.

Comment: Hi I got them to change the url to the correct path. is there a way to log any 404 or 400 responses to view what is being sent to the web api?

Comment: If it worked, please mark the answer as accepted. When it comes to logging there are many different options available. Least effort may be just looking at the server access logs.